# Given -D %s busybox v1.30.1 complains about invalid date

Tags: linux, date, sh, busybox

I've been looking for a solution online but couldn't find anything useful.

Running the same command works on busybox 1.29.2 but no longer on 1.30.1.

We are trying to offset the date by running this command:

```
echo $(date -D %s +%m%d%H%M  -d "$(($(date +%s) - 4200))")
```

on 1.29.2 it gives the **correct** output
on 1.30.1 it gives the error message **date: invalid date '1592225794'**

Did something change syntax-wise? Any other ideas how to offset the date by for example +2 hours? Ideal output format is `%m%d%H%M`.

Comment: Would you be able to get configuration options that your busybox was configured with? It is possible that [the DATE_ISOFMT feature](https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/master/coreutils/date.c#L196) is just turned off in your second build.

Comment: @KamilCuk I don't think so. Portable specifiers work fine, for instance `date -D %j -d 1`. `%s` is a glibc extension, that might be the culprit.

Comment: You are right. From what I see, `busybox` just internally calls `strptime`. So `strptime` without `%s` support will error. @thblx On what systems are you testing the outputs? Different onces? I guess you are running 1.30.1 on some alpine vs. running the other on system with glibc.

Comment: @KamilCuk it is the same container for etcd control in docker just different version. only notable difference is the busybox version. Containers running on power architecture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what they changed, but `-D %s` is redundant there; busybox date supports `-d @SECONDS_SINCE_EPOCH` since version 1.17.x.

```
$ date +%m%d%H%M -d @$(($(date +%s)-4200))
06151525
$ date
Mon Jun 15 16:35:22 +03 2020
```

Comment: Hi, that worked.. thanks . I guess the syntax did change slightly since it worked in one version of busybox and in the other not..  I'll update the scripts so they work also on the new containers :)